# Assigning values of 4*4 matrix

Tags: matrix, verilog

I'm trying to create a  4*4 matrix in this form:

> 2 3 1 1
>   1 2 3 1
>   1 1 2 3 
>   3 1 1 2

Then I need to assign the values element in each location to multiply by 4 inputs each one 8 bits.

```
a0, a1, a2, a3
```

I have tried to write this code :

```
module Mix_Nibbles_Matriex(
  out_0,out_1,out_2,out_3,nibble_0,nibble_1,nibble_2,nibble_3,
  clk,rst,load  
);

  input clk,rst,load ;
  output reg [7:0] out_0,out_1,out_2,out_3;
  input [7:0] nibble_0,nibble_1,nibble_2,nibble_3; 
  //wire matrix[3:0][0:3];

  reg [1:0][7:0] a_unpacked_array[4];

  always @( posedge clk or negedge rst)
  if (!rst)
    a_unpacked_array[0][0]=0;
  else if (load)
    assign a_unpacked_array[0][0]=2;
    assign a_unpacked_array[0][1]=3;
    assign a_unpacked_array[0][2]=1;
    assign a_unpacked_array[0][3]=1;

    assign a_unpacked_array[1][0]=2;
    assign a_unpacked_array[1][1]=3;
    assign a_unpacked_array[1][2]=1;
    assign a_unpacked_array[1][3]=1;

    assign a_unpacked_array[2][0]=2;
    assign a_unpacked_array[2][1]=3;
    assign a_unpacked_array[2][2]=1;
    assign a_unpacked_array[2][3]=1;

    assign a_unpacked_array[3][0]=2;
    assign a_unpacked_array[3][1]=3;
    assign a_unpacked_array[3][2]=1;
    assign a_unpacked_array[3][3]=1;

    //display ("a_unpacked_array      = %b", a_unpacked_array);
endmodule
```

I'm still have these errors:

> ERROR:HDLCompiler:939 - "D:/Embedded_Project/Mix_Nibbles_Matriex.v" Line 38: Single value range is not allowed in this mode of verilog
>   ERROR:HDLCompiler:1439 - "D:/Embedded_Project/Mix_Nibbles_Matriex.v" Line 38: Multiple packed dimensions are not allowed in this mode of verilog
>   ERROR:HDLCompiler:1417 - "D:/Embedded_Project/Mix_Nibbles_Matriex.v" Line 44: Bit-select or part-select is not allowed in a assign statement for non-net a_unpacked_array
>   ERROR:HDLCompiler:598 - "D:/Embedded_Project/Mix_Nibbles_Matriex.v" Line 27: Module  ignored due to previous errors.

Answer (score 0):

There are couple problems with your code.

1. Verilog doesn't support multiple packed dimensions. You'd [need](http://forums.xilinx.com/t5/Synthesis/2-dimensional-array-decleration-in-verilog/td-p/259320) to use SystemVerilog to make this construct work. You can also follow @Greg suggestion to use unpacked dimension.
2. `reg [1:0][7:0] a_unpacked_array[4];` - compiler tries to treat `4` as range, but single value range are not allowed. Maybe what you meant is `[3:0]`? Also `[1:0]` should be probably `[3:0]`.
3. Your `always` block has some issues: missing `begin-end`, unnecessary `assign` keywords, etc.:

   ```
   always @(posedge clk or negedge rst)
     if (!rst) begin
       a_unpacked_array[0][0] <= 0;
       //...
     end else if (load) begin
       a_unpacked_array[0][0] <= 2;
       //...
     end
   ```

Comment: Thanks alot, I have modified the code as you mentioned in your reply but I still have this error :Multiple packed dimensions are not allowed in this mode of verilog..                                                                                 Note :I have ISE Project navigator version 14.6 copyright(c) 1995-2013 ...Is it ok        @Qiu

Comment: Please i tried to mention you in the above comment  –  Qiu

Comment: @user2014, The error message says ":Multiple packed dimensions are not allowed", so try Multiple unpacked dimensions: `reg [7:0] a_unpacked_array [0:3] [0:3];`

Comment: @user2014: sorry for the confusion, I've edited my answer a little bit.